# Questions about using the smali library

Tags: java, android, dalvik, dex, smali

I have a smali file and I want to know how to convert the smali file into an `org.jf.dexlib2.iface.ClassDef` object via the smali library.

I have an idea now: The dex file of the smali file will be obtained by the `baksmali.disassembleDexFile()` a method, and a new DexFile object can be generated to obtain the `org.jf.dexlib2.iface.ClassDef` object, but if the dex is large enough, it is too expensive.

So ask everyone to help me.

Comment: Open it as raw text, and decode the bytes a little bit. You may eventually begin to see that dex byte code is just a tad different from java's .class byte code

Answer (score 2):

If you have the dex file itself, just use `DexFileFactory.loadDexFile("/path/to/dex/file.dex", Opcodes.getDefault());`, and then iterate over the classes until you find the ClassDef of the class you're interested in.

If you don't have a dex file, just use smali to assemble the smali file to a dex file first.